# PostgreSQL primary key length limit

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, varchar

What is the limit of the length of primary key column? I'm going to use varchar as primary key. I've found no info, how long it can be, since PostgreSQL does not require to specify varchar limit when used as primary key?

Comment: I see, I can put a lot of data in such primary key, but it is not a good idea. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that maximum varchar length is a Postgres configuration setting.  However, it looks as though it can't exceed 1GB in size.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_maximum_size_for_a_row.2C_a_table.2C_and_a_database.3F

That having been said, it's probably not a good idea to have a large varchar column as a primary key.  Consider using a serial or bigserial (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)

Comment: +1 for noting that varchar is a bad PK. This will give bad performance when using within reference tables (I changed your link to the most recent PG version).

Comment: @DrColossos:  This is ONLY true if you are using said varchar field as a Foreign Key in another table.  If that field is simply required to be UNIQUE and NOT NULL *and* only referenced in that one table, then adding a numeric "PRIMARY KEY" will actually hurt you.  You will now to incur the overhead of both the numeric PK *and* the additional UNIQUE INDEX on the NOT NULL varchar column (required in order to ensure data integrity).  It's fine advice when talking about foreign keys, but to say "varchar is a bad PK" is misleading.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for the follow up :D Wasn't fully aware of the details and how to interpret my comment. I though "[...]when using within reference tables[...]" was clear enough that I meant Foreign Keys but you clearly gave more insight into this topic. Now I know better, thank you!

Comment: Two more alternatives: [1] Use a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as primary key, with efficient native (128-bit) storage in Postgres. [2] Calculate, store, and index a [hash value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to represent your large text. Discussed in this [other question's answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69164/19079) by Erwin Brandstetter

Answer (score 29):

The maximum length for a value in a B-tree index, which includes primary keys, is one third of the size of a buffer page, by default floor(8192/3) = **2730** bytes.

Comment: That's 2600 chars in UTF-8

Comment: How is that? A unicode character can consist of [up to 4 bytes](https://webwizards.com/post/max-bytes-in-a-utf-8-char) when encoded in utf-8. So how do you arrive at 2600? I would expect 2730 / 4 = **`682`** (rounded down).

Comment: Previous comments to this answer are misleading. The limit is on *bytes*, not characters. UTF-8 characters occupy 1 - 4 bytes per character, that would translate to 682 - 2730 characters. But that's not the whole story. There is an additional 4-byte header for long `text` values. But then long strings are typically **compressed**. The actual (compressed) size on disk, plus item identifier and header per index tuple (4+8 bytes) matters. The maximum index tuple size was slightly reduced repeatedly, and is currently (Postgres 15) **2704 bytes** . See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217088/3684

Answer (score 5):

You should made a test.

I've made tests, with table, that have single varchar column as primary key, on PostgreSQL 8.4. The result is, that I was able to store 235000 ASCII characters, 116000 polish diactrical characters (f.g. 'ć') or 75000 chinese (f.g. '汉'). For larger sets I've got a message: 
BŁĄD: index row size 5404 exceeds btree maximum, 2712

However, the message told that:
Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.

So the values were allowed, however not the whole string was used for uniqueness check.

Well, this is a very large amount of data that you can put in that column. However, as noted above, your design is poor if you will have to use such long values as keys. You should use artificial primary key.